# getting week from the date in sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to how i can split the month into respective weeks based on the user entry, like from 1day of the month or by first week of the week.

example:
if user wants data based on 1day of the month i.e., 01-06-2012
then

jun'2012
1/6-7/6  8/6-14/6  15/6-21/6  22/6-28/6 29/6-30/6

if the user wants according to first week i.e., 4-6-2012

jun-2012
4-10   11-17  18-24
i think this will be a fiscal week

can anyone please tell me how i can get this?

and how to get the complete week based on the given date

Answer (score 0):

This could give u an idea,

```
declare
vdate date := sysdate;  
temp  Date;
begin
temp  :=  VDate;
WHILE last_day(temp) >=  vDate
LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line(to_char(vDate));
   vDate := vDate+7;
END LOOP;
end;

end;
```

The result will be starting from to day (10th Dec 2012) to the last day of this week

```
    10-DEC-12
    17-DEC-12
    24-DEC-12
    .....
```